# Double-Check-Locking guarantees state of the object ? (concurrency in practice)

Tags: java, concurrency, double-checked-locking

I am reading concurrency in practice and have some misunderstanding.
quote:

> the real problem with DCL is the assumption that the worst thing that
>   can happen when reading the shared object reference without
>   synchronization is to erroneously see a stale value (in this case,
>   null); in that cse the DCL idiom compensates for this risk by trying
>   again with the lock held. But the worst case is actually considerably
>   wrong - it is possible to see a current value of the reference but
>   **stale values for the object's states**, meaning that the object could be
>   seen to be in an invalid or incorrect state.

after Brian Goetz writes that DCL will work in current memory model using volatile:

```
public class DoubleCheckLociing{

   private static volatile Resource resource;

   public static Resource getInstance(){
       if(resource == null){
           synchronized(DoubleCheckLociing.class){
               if(resource == null){
                   resource = new Resource();
               }
            }
       } 
       return resource;
   }
}
```

I am not sure if understand the phrase about state correct.

Lets imagine that `Resource` class looks like this:

```
class Resource{
    private Date date = new Date();//mutable thread unsafe class
    private int k = 10;

    public Date getDate(){
        return date;
    }

   public int getK(){
        return k;
    }

}
```

Does I have guaranties that `getInstance` always return `correct` resource which always return correct `k` (10) and `date`?

Comment: *Does I have guaranties that getInstance always return correct resource which always return correct k (10) and date?*. So you just want a confirmation whether *Brian Goetz* is right?

Comment: I need confirmation that my understanding correct. My previous understanding was strictly another. I thought that problem with 2 reads of shared reference. First can return !=nul but second can be null

Comment: And you did not find a single answer on the site that confirmed this?

Comment: I am not strong in termins thus I cannot build search string properly

Comment: What does the `dcl` (Digital Command Language) tag have to do with this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `volatile` in place you do have those guarantees.  Without the `volatile` you do not.

When one thread writes the volatile variable `resource`, the operation includes a 'memory barrier' that ensures that everything it wrote before that, like the initialization of the instance fields, is written out to system memory first.

When another thread reads `resource`, it includes a memory barrier that ensures that no reads performed after that will see values that were cached from system memory before that read.

These two memory barriers ensure that if a thread sees an initialized `resource` variable, then it will also see properly initialized fields in that object.

Answer (score 0):

> Does I have guaranties that getInstance always return correct resource which always return correct k (10) and date?

Yes and no.  As @Matt points out, if the field is `volatile` then you are guaranteed that all of the fields of `Resource` will be published appropriately when it is accessed by another thread which is the important part of the double-check-locking example you quote.  The `volatile` memory-barriers ensure this.

However, your `Resource` contains non-final fields that may be mutable (if a setter method was added or not listed).  If you make your fields `final` then actually you can dispense with the `volatile` because `final` fields are guaranteed to be published when the reference to your `Resource` is published.

```
private final Date date = new Date();
private final int k = 10;
```

As you mention however, this doesn't fully save you because `Date` is also mutable.  You need to make sure that your code (or other code) does not call any setter methods on the `date` field, then you will be ok.

This is a good example about how important it is to track mutability in threaded programs.

Comment: But if I don't execute matations of my objects I have guaranties to see values I set in constructor(inline in my case)

Comment: If they are final yes.  If they are not final then the `volatile` gives you those guarantees, yes @gstackoverflow.